# Add a column with Not Null

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ddl

I have a existing table in which i am adding a column as `NgoId` whose datatype is `int`. I want to add as `NOT NULL` to the column .

When I'm adding this I am getting the following error:

> Unable to modify table.    Cannot insert the value NULL into column
>   'NgoId', table 'CSR.dbo.Tmp_tbl_post_category'; column does not allow
>   nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

Please help how to add the column with NOT NULL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you already have data in the table, you cannot add a `NOT NULL` field, because the existing data will already violate the `NOT NULL` constraint.

You therefore have 2 choices:

a) Add the column with a `DEFAULT` value...

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Tmp_tbl_post_category ADD NgoId INT DEFAULT 1;
```

...then run an update statement to correct the values to what they should actually be

b) Truncate the data from the table, add the column and then re-populate the table...

```
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.Tmp_tbl_post_category;

ALTER TABLE dbo.Tmp_tbl_post_category ADD NgoId INT;

INSERT INTO dbo.Tmp_tbl_post_category...
```